# Angular Observable combinelatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to build a component that access a service and return an observable with a list of objects to populate a table

My service has a  function :

```js
public getTranches(): Observable<Tranche[]> {
    this.loadTranches(); //this calls the rest API to populate the variable _tranches
    return this._tranches.asObservable(); // return variable <BehaviourSubject>_tranches asObservable 
  }
```

My Component consists of a table displaying the data through:

```js
this.subscription = this.apiService
   .getTranches()
     .subscribe(
      (data) => {
       this.tranches = data;
       }
  );
```

html:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let tranche of tranches">
   // stuff
</ng-container>
```

Up util here everything works fine.

I added a input and click events to the table headers

```html
//header example for sortby
<div (click)="this.filters.sortby = name"></div>

//input for filter
<input (keyup)="this.filters.search = $event.target.value" type="text">
```

and a variable filters to store that information

can you show me how to transform the filter variable in a observable and merge it to a single subscription to feed the table so I can perform the filtering and sorting on the component?

I've tried using filter as behaviourSubject and use combineLatest to merge them unsuccessfully if that is the way to do it can I see an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a class variable **_tranches** which is a *BehaviorSubject* and emits, via the `next()` method, an array **arr** of items that get displayed by the table.

If this is true, in order to achieve filtering and sorting, you have to do the following things:

- store the array **arr** somewhere (e.g. as a private class variable)
- when *sort* or *filter* commands are fired from UI, apply `filter` and
  `sort` methods to the array **arr**
- take the results of these methods and use them as arguments for the `next()` method of the **BehaviorSubject**

Then honestly I do not understand how the *click* and *keyup* events are managed in your code, but this does not affect the previous points.

Answer (score 0):

assume it start off from a onSearch function bind to a user action to trigger api call

```
filters=new BehaviorSubject({sortby:'',search:''})
onSearch=()=>{
filters.map(obj=>{
// asume you will need to add a object param in getTranches to deal with sortby and search
return this.apiService.getTranches(obj)
}).subscribe();
}
```

in your html

```
<div (click)="this.filters.next({sortby:name})"></div>
<input (keyup)="this.filters.next({search:$event.target.value})" type="text">
```